# Why this code runs perfectly in visual studio with multibyte characher set but not with unicode char set?

Tags: c++, windows, api

when I run this code on g++ , it runs smoothly, but when I run this code on visual studio wiith unicode char set option, it doesn't print product id. 
can you explain me how to fix this problem and why it happens?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

wchar_t* GetRegistryKeyValue(const char* RegKey, const char* pPIDName)
{
    HKEY        Registry;
    long        ReturnStatus;
    DWORD       regType = 0;
    DWORD       regSize = 0;
    char*       pPID = 0;
    ReturnStatus = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, RegKey, 0, KEY_QUERY_VALUE | KEY_WOW64_64KEY, &Registry);
    if (ReturnStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        ReturnStatus = RegQueryValueEx(Registry, pPIDName, 0, &regType, 0, &regSize);
        pPID = new char[regSize];

        /* Get Value. */
        ReturnStatus = RegQueryValueEx(Registry, pPIDName, 0, &regType, (LPBYTE)pPID, &regSize);


        RegCloseKey(Registry);

        if (pPID[regSize] > 127 || pPID[regSize] < 32)
        {
            pPID[regSize] = '\0';
        }

        if (regSize > 1)
        {

            int s = 0;
            int i=0;
            while (pPID[i] != NULL)
            {
                s++;
                i++;
            }


            const size_t cSize = s ;
            wchar_t* wc = new wchar_t[cSize];
            mbstowcs(wc, pPID, cSize);  

            return wc;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Size not > 1 (%d)\n", regSize);
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        RegCloseKey(Registry);
        return NULL;
    }
}
int main()
{
    wchar_t * resultData=NULL;  
    resultData = GetRegistryKeyValue("SOFTWARE\\MICROSOFT\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", "ProductId");
    wcout << resultData;
    cout << endl;
    delete resultData;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are lucky, if this appears to work at all. Calling `delete` on a pointer allocated using `new[]` is undefined behavior. Your real issue, however, is your reinterpreting of ANSI-encoded character strings as if they were UTF-16.

Comment: thypecasting RegKey and pPID to lpcwstr seems good with no syntax error  when unicode char set option is selected, but RegQueryValueEx returned 2 in this case which is not supposed to happen.

Comment: if `pPID = new char[regSize]` then surely `pPID[regSize]` is out-of-bounds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `TCHAR`-based APIs that rely on `char*` data when compiling for MBCS and `wchar_t*` data when compiling for Unicode.  You are not taking that difference into account correctly.  Your code should not even compile when set for Unicode, because you would be passing ANSI parameters to Unicode functions.  Since you want to return a Unicode string, you should be using the Unicode API functions to begin with.

There are other logic errors in your code, such as leaking memory, not allocating the right number of bytes for the `wc` buffer, insufficient error handling, etc.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

wchar_t* GetRegistryKeyValue(const wchar_t* RegKey, const wchar_t* pValueName)
{
    long        ReturnStatus;
    DWORD       regType = 0;
    DWORD       regSize = 0;
    DWORD dwFlags = RRF_RT_REG_SZ | RRF_RT_REG_MULTI_SZ | RRF_RT_REG_EXPAND_SZ | RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY;
    wchar_t* ws = 0;

    ReturnStatus = RegGetValueW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, RegKey, pValueName, dwFlags, &regType, 0, &regSize);
    if (ReturnStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        ws = new wchar_t[regSize / sizeof(WCHAR)];

        ReturnStatus = RegGetValueW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, RegKey, pValueName, dwFlags, &regType, ws, &regSize);
        if (ReturnStatus != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {
            delete[] ws;
            ws = NULL;
        }
    }

    return ws;
}

int main()
{
    wchar_t* resultData = GetRegistryKeyValue(L"SOFTWARE\\MICROSOFT\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", L"ProductId");
    wcout << resultData << endl;
    delete[] resultData;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

wstring GetRegistryKeyValue(const wchar_t* RegKey, const wchar_t* pValueName)
{
    long        ReturnStatus;
    DWORD       regType = 0;
    DWORD       regSize = 0;
    DWORD dwFlags = RRF_RT_REG_SZ | RRF_RT_REG_MULTI_SZ | RRF_RT_REG_EXPAND_SZ | RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY;

    ReturnStatus = RegGetValueW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, RegKey, pValueName, dwFlags, &regType, 0, &regSize);
    if (ReturnStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS)
    {
        vector<BYTE> buf;
        buf.resize(regSize);

        ReturnStatus = RegGetValueW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, RegKey, pValueName, dwFlags, &regType, &buf[0], &regSize);
        if (ReturnStatus == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            return wstring((wchar_t*)&buf[0], (regSize / sizeof(WCHAR)) - 1);
    }

    return wstring();
}

int main()
{
    wcout << GetRegistryKeyValue(L"SOFTWARE\\MICROSOFT\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion", L"ProductId") << endl;
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ReturnStatus = RegGetValueW(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, RegKey, pValueName, dwFlags, &regType, &ws[0], &regSize);
there is an error in &ws[0].

Comment: your first code didn't work and the flag RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY gives me an error in visual studio, instead I used hex value of it and it works!

Comment: I have replaced flag with hex value.

Comment: I fixed the `&ws[0]` error. But what other errors are you getting? What did you have to change?

Comment: I used your first code, 2nd wasn't working.
Replaced flag value with hex value.

Comment: can you tell my how can i read and write registry files using these functions prototypes?
int write_file(RegistryHive, RegistryLocation, RegistryKey, SourceFile)
int read_file(RegistryHive, RegistryLocation, RegistryKey, DestinationFile)

Comment: It sounds like you are not using a version of the Windows SDK that defines `RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY`, so just define it manually in your own code: `#ifndef RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY #define RRF_SUBKEY_WOW6464KEY 0x00010000 #endif`.  As for your other issue, that deserves its own question posted separately.

Comment: Can you please help me here? As i am new to stackoverflow and I have limited  numbers of asking questions.

Comment: @usamamw141: StackOverflow [limits how often](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4359/) you can post a new question, but it does not limit the total number of questions you can post. So just post a new question about the registry file issue when time allows. It does not belong on this question.

Answer (score 0):

According to this documentation:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/mbstowcs/

> If max characters are successfully translated, the resulting string stored in dest is not null-terminated.

The tricky way you're trying to calculate string length (which, btw, could be replaced by `strlen(pPID)` ) will skip the `'\0'` in the first string and thus the result might not have `'\0'` on the end. Why don't you use `regSize` there?

Comment: the main problem that I am facing is that when I use typecasting of const 
char* RegKey, const char* pPIDName to lpcwstr,
pPID[regsize] set to null.
I want to have windows pid in pPID[] with unicode cha set settings turned on in visual studio.